# React js window.print freezes the page

Tags: reactjs

In my project using React with Typescript I am trying to print a div with some data.
Basicaly This div is in a modal, I gave it an id (id='printablediv'). Then when you press print on the modal I run this function :

```
    const Print = () => {
        let printContents = document.getElementById('printablediv')?.innerHTML!;
        let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document!.body!.innerHTML! = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        setIsModalOpen(false)
    }
```

Then problem is that when I click print and the print page opens and I print the div, after that the page freezes. and I cant do anything. I have to reload the page. Even if i don't print and press cancel, it still freezes. Has anyone encountered with problem?
I am trying not to use a library such as react-to-print.

Edit:
This is where i call the Print function:

```
             <TicketModal
                    isOpen={isTicketModalOpen}
                    onAnulla={onCloseTicketModal}
                    onPrint={Print}
                    code={createResponseCode}
                    pin={createResponsePin}
                    id={user.uid}
                    currency={createResponseCurrency}
                    amount={createResponseAmount}
                />
```

the onPrint is the prop connected to the modal button

```
<Button size="lg"
   variant="primary"
   className='ticket-modal-card__button'
   onClick={onPrint}
   >
   Print Ticket</Button>
```

Comment: Can you add what event call print function

Comment: Basically is called on the button onClick.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Apparently the problem is I'm removing the original content, and then replacing it with new, different content, so all the event listeners and metadata react had attached to the original content is lost. innerHTML doesn't include those things (setting innerHTML is probably never what you actually want to do in any situation).

To print just part of a page, I set up a print stylesheet that changes the styling of your page when printing, and not change the HTML itself.

```
    .printme {
        display: none;
    }
    @media print {
        .no-printme  {
            display: none;
        }
        .printme  {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

This way I can Display and hide everything I want and print only the part I need.